# Could not create Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener."}

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api2, azure-application-insights

I have enabled my app insight in web api app and it works fine in local. When i deploy to azure webapp and while accessing my web api method, it gives the below error.

```
Could not create Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener.ApplicationInsightsTraceListener, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener."}
```

What should i do ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: it works fine in local but when deployed to azure it give following error.

Comment: Have you enable Application Insights in the web app?

Comment: Show use some (relevant) code, like how you're enabling App Insights in your application. Also: do you have an instrumentation key set in the Azure environment?

Comment: Have you checked "SETTINGS>Application Insights" of your app service on Azure Portal?Since you have built Application Insights into your web app code, it should work as expected,you could use [kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) to check your deployed contents and compare with your local side to narrow this issue.Moreover, you could apply Application Insights to your app at runtime,details you could follow [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now).

Comment: Have you checked "SETTINGS>Application Insights" of your app service on Azure Portal?Since you have built Application Insights into your web app code, it should work as expected,you could use [kudu](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2014/03/24/using-kudu-with-windows-azure-web-sites/) to check your deployed contents and compare with your local side to narrow this issue.Moreover, you could apply Application Insights to your app at runtime,details you could follow [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-monitor-performance-live-website-now).

Comment: what's the rest of the message?  there should be some more details about why, like if it couldn't find an assembly, or a dependency.  chances are, when deployed to azure, you're missing deploying some assemblies?